# log4net config transform in VS2013 - is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, log4net

is it achievable to have log4net.config to be transformed in VS2013? I'm getting the following error:

Error   31  "App.config;obj\Release\app.exe.config" is an invalid value for the "ConfigFile" parameter of the "GenerateApplicationManifest" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".

Answer (score 0):

just found the answer..   manually edit the project file

```
 <Target Name="ApplyLoggingConfiguration" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="Exists('log4net.$(Configuration).config')">
    <TransformXml Source="log4net.config" Transform="log4net.$(Configuration).config" Destination="log4net.config" />
  </Target>
```

[How to transform log4net config like web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557866/how-to-transform-log4net-config-like-web-config)